# Why SelectMany needs the one of M<S> -> (S -> M<C>) -> (S -> M<C> -> R) -> E<R>?

Tags: c#, monads

In the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631(v=vs.110).aspx, the third signature is

```
// M<S> -> (S -> M<C>) -> (S -> M<C> -> R) -> E<R>
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectMany<TSource, TCollection, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TCollection>> collectionSelector,
    Func<TSource, TCollection, TResult> resultSelector
)
```

Shouldn't the first one which has the signature of the typical Monad bind function `M<A> -> (A -> M<B>) -> M<B>` be enough? Isn't it easy to merge code in the `resultSelector` into `collectionSelector`?

The MSDN document gave an example to show the usage of the method.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SelectManyEx3();
    }
    public static void SelectManyEx3()
    {
        PetOwner[] petOwners =
            { new PetOwner { Name="Higa",
                    Pets = new List<string>{ "Scruffy", "Sam" } },
                new PetOwner { Name="Ashkenazi",
                    Pets = new List<string>{ "Walker", "Sugar" } },
                new PetOwner { Name="Price",
                    Pets = new List<string>{ "Scratches", "Diesel" } },
                new PetOwner { Name="Hines",
                    Pets = new List<string>{ "Dusty" } } };

        // Project the pet owner's name and the pet's name.
        var query =
            petOwners
            .SelectMany(petOwner => petOwner.Pets, (petOwner, petName) => new { petOwner, petName })
            .Where(ownerAndPet => ownerAndPet.petName.StartsWith("S"))
            .Select(ownerAndPet =>
                    new
                    {
                        Owner = ownerAndPet.petOwner.Name,
                        Pet = ownerAndPet.petName
                    }
            );

        // Print the results.
        foreach (var obj in query1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj);
        }
    }
}

class PetOwner
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Pets { get; set; }
}
```

However, the `var query = ...` can be rewritten using the `SelectMany` of the first signature as following?

```
var query = petOwners.SelectMany(o => o.Pets.Select(p => new { petOwner = o, petName =p}))
```

When will the `SelectMany` with the third signature be really useful?

Comment: I think the third signature example is more simple to understand and more concise than to create a LINQ subexpression.

Comment: Is there any example?

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd and 4th overloads of the SelectMany( ) method with the additional “result selector” parameter take a bit more explanation.

The extra selector parameter is trying to help you know and understand the relationship between the parent and child collections. The code is more concise concerned the relationship.

A result selector is an intermediate object available within the scope of the query to give you the information you need, and it’s up to you to decide what data you need in the result selector to help you.

Say you need a result collection that will not only have the full list of Teams that match some criteria in all leagues but need to know what League the teams are in.

For example:

```
var teamsAndTheirLeagues = from helper in leagues
    .SelectMany( l => l.Teams, ( league, team ) 
    => new { league, team } )
    where helper.team.Players.Count > 2 
        && helper.league.Teams.Count < 10
    select new { LeagueID = helper.league.ID, Team = helper.team };
```

This syntax gives you extra ability to query both the team and the league in the where clause and you are not "losing" backward connection of the parent-child relationship.

More detailed explanation about selectMany projections can be found [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/6bcc95/understanding-projections-in-linq-with-select-selectmany-e/) and [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/27/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-9-selectmany/)

Comment: It seems the example can be rewritten as `var teamsAndTheirLeagues = from helper in leagues
    .SelectMany( l => l.Teams.Select(x => new {league = l, team = x}) where ....`?

Comment: Yes, but this is also extra typing. The third signature is more concise and saves this extra typings.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been more helpful if they used the example like below. See how I added a `Where` clause in the `SelectMany`. This overload gives you the flexibility to run a query and then do a projection on the result of that query:

```
// Project the pet owner's name and the pet's name.
var query =
    petOwners
    .SelectMany(petOwner => petOwner.Pets.Where(x => x.StartsWith("S")), (petOwner, petName) => new { petOwner, petName })
    //.Where(ownerAndPet => ownerAndPet.petName.StartsWith("S"))
    .Select(ownerAndPet =>
            new
            {
                Owner = ownerAndPet.petOwner.Name,
                Pet = ownerAndPet.petName
            }
    );
```

Comment: To use the first signature, it can be rewritten as `petOwners
    .SelectMany(petOwner => petOwner.Pets.Where(x => x.StartsWith("S")).Select(petName => new {petOwner, petName}).Select(ownerAndPet => ....`?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 Of course it can be. But it is for convenience so you can do a projection on the result within the same method. If you think it does something that cannot be re-written differently, it does not.